# Cakephp - import 10k lines of email adresses

Tags: php, cakephp, foreach

I have a script that reads about 10k lines of a txt file with an email address in each line.
For each address I do a check if its already in use and if yes I put the address into an `error` array, if not I put the address int an `save` array.

After the foreach and if no addreses are in the error array, I do a `$this->Newsletter->saveMany($data)`.

For some reason, I always get a timeout, when I import more than about 500 lines.
Is there a way to go another / better way to avoid the timeout?

Please advice!

```
public function import() {
        $filename = './files/newsletterImport/newsletter.txt';

            $lines = file($filename);
            foreach ($lines as $line_num => $line) {

                // check unique
                if($email = $this->Newsletter->find('first', array('conditions' => array('email' => trim($line))))){
                    $error[$line_num]['email'] = trim($line);
                    $error[$line_num]['cancel'] = date('d.m.Y H:i:s', strtotime($email['Newsletter']['cancel']));
                }else{
                    $data[$line_num]['Newsletter']['email'] = trim($line);
                    $data[$line_num]['Newsletter']['active'] = 1;
                }

            }
            if(!$error){
                $this->Newsletter->create();
                if($this->Newsletter->saveMany($data)){
                    $this->set('msg', 'Success');
                }else{
                    $this->set('msg', 'Error! Nothing imported!');
                }
            }else{
                $this->set('msg', 'Error! Nothing imported!');
                $this->set('error', $error);
            }
        }else{
            $this->set('msg', 'No file found!');
        }
```

Comment: have you tried using [Xdebug](http://www.xdebug.org/docs/profiler)? It may help pinpoint the issue.

Comment: I would say to store such amount of addresses in a database table instead.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't really know when you time out, a few tips.

1) Meassure the time for every bit of code, unless you know what is the part that's taking you most of the time available.

2) You do a query to the DB each for each line, that's 10k worth of queries... My heart hurts. So, consider doing a big query to get all emails, and compare them with php to know if they are unique. Again, time it, maybe the SQL option turns out to be more efficient (depends on how you do the search on a PHP array)

3) Try adjusting [the options](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-savemany-array-data-null-array-options-array) of the save. The atomic option is true by default, and that probably is a bit too much to a 10k save.

```
$this->Newsletter->saveMany($data, array('atomic'=>false));
```

If that those not solve the problem, try to divide the array and save it by stages. I know it a pain, but maybe the transaction is just too much.